# How to share session with subdomains with grails on localhost (dev mode)?

Tags: session, tomcat, grails, grails-plugin

I have a grails app wich has different subdomains, for example:
dashboard.domain.tld and app.domain.tld and so on.

I have this setup working online on my tomcat (with session shared between the subdomains) but i need to test this offline in development environment.

I created some hosts, e.g.:
dashboard.localhost.dev and app.localhost.dev and this seems to work, but i always have to relogin each time i visit a different subdomain.

How can i configure grails / tomcat plugin to share session / cookie subdomain wide?

Comment: You can configure your embedded Tomcat, see: http://roshandawrani.wordpress.com/2011/03/13/grails-tip-configuring-embedded-tomcat-instance-used-in-developmenttest-env/

Comment: Hi Sergio, i created an event script but how can i configure tomcat (context) to share sessions between multiple domains? How do i set sessionCookieDomain ?

Comment: The link says that Tomcat is this class: http://www.docjar.com/docs/api/org/apache/catalina/startup/Tomcat.html You need to look for the setSessionCookieDomain method somewhere (can be a related class).

Comment: I didn't get it working :-(

Comment: Can you share what you already tried?

Comment: I didn't find the setSessionCookieDomain method.

Answer (score -1):

Even it's old question, My solution was to create _Events.groovy script with following:

```
eventConfigureTomcat = {tomcat ->
    def context = tomcat.host.findChild("")
    context.setSessionCookieDomain(".domain.tld")
    context.setSessionCookiePath("/")
}
```

Comment: Failed to start: Cannot invoke method setSessionCookieDomain() on null object